# Why won't Android Studio install all of it's components?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I'm trying to install Android Studio, but whenever I attempt to, it stops downloading here:

[image: Where the download gets stuck at]

Comment: is your internet working fine ? and have you run your android studio with admin permission ?

Comment: It turned out to be an internet thing. Thanks